# Can you control the garbage rows in some way?

Tags: tetris-99

When garbage rows are sent your way, they sometimes have the gap in the same place, allowing you to clear up to four rows at once with a single line piece. Other times however, the gaps are scattered in different places, meaning you have to clear the rows one after the other to carve your way down.

When does this happen? Can I somehow influence the garbage rows to have the gap at the same place? Or is this just the result of a single player sending me all their garbage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each inserted line, there's a high percentage that the garbage shows up with the hole in the same column as the previous garbage line.
It depends on how the garbage was sent to you. If it was all sent at once (via tetris or back to back tetris) it'll all be in the same line. If it was given from multiple people or was combo damage it'll be split up.

**So, long answer short, you cannot influence it**